# "How much are you offering "? "What is your offer"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, questions

If I am selling a house, Could you pls tell me that who could say these qestions? Seller or buyer or both(as in anyone)

Comment: Sellers offer their house for sale and set an *asking price*. Interested buyers say they have a different number in mind, usually lower. So, sellers ask them either "How much are you offering?" or "What is your offer?" Same question as for that rug in the bazaar.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin. "Do not you think, buyer can also say, 'What is your offer on TV'? ?" ( As buyer is looking for any discount or buy one get one free offer)

Comment: But 'special offers' are normally on goods in shops, not on individual deals like house sales.

Comment: offers are always from sellers, not buyers. It's quite simple really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What is your offer?

This sentence can be said to anyone who is *offering* a deal or contract. In terms of buying/selling a house, this would almost always be the buyer, not the seller. (So the seller would say this to the buyer.) That's because culturally, in most English speaking countries, the buyer is the one who makes the offer on a house.

In other sale situations, this could be said by either the buyer or the seller -  to whoever is proposing a price or deal.

### How much are you offering?

This is similar to the other sentence but different because the word "much" means amount, so the answer has to be an amount of money or something else that can have an amount.

In a house-buying situation, this would be almost always said by the seller to the buyer for the same reasons as above.

In other situations, it is less likely that a buyer would say this to a seller because the context would not usually apply.

### Other Situations

In situations other than selling/buying a house, these sentences might be said when something is being sold or bought or when a different deal or trade is being offered. Here are some examples of that:

*I am in a bazaar or market. I walk up to a shop selling shirts. The conversation might go like this:*

> Shopkeeper: This shirt would look great on you.
> Me: My closet is full! I don't need more shirts. But how much are you asking for it?
> Shopkeeper: It's $40, but it would match your eyes.
> Me: I do kind of like it, but that's far too much.
> Shopkeeper: Well then, **how much are you offering?**
> Me: I could give you $25.

*I'm walking home and stop at a corner market to pick up food for dinner. When I walk in, the shopkeeper greets me and wants to tell me about a special deal. The conversation might go like this:*

> Shopkeeper: Hello, good afternoon! We have a special deal on melons today. Are you interested?
> Me: I do love melon! **What is the offer?**
> Shopkeeper: 2 melons for $5.

*I am looking for a new job and recently completed interviews for a job that I'm interested in. I get a phone call from the hiring manager.*

> Manager: Good morning, I'm calling to tell you that we'd love to offer you the job!
> Me: That's great news! Thank you very much. **Could you tell me more about your offer**?
> Manager: Based on your experience, we are able to offer you $70,000 / year and a full benefits package.

Comment: Could you pls also explain your this statement? In other sale situations, this could be said by either the buyer or the seller - to whoever is proposing a price or deal.

Comment: @BilalZafar Absolutely! I added a few more examples to the end. Could you take a look and see if that answered your question?

Comment: @ Friendly Racoon thank you for an indepth analysis with examples. Yes your examples made me understand. I appreciate.